# How to pull row number of the last row containing a specific text?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, max, row

I want to pull the row number of the last row conataining a specific text and the data is sorted randomly in google sheet. For example, I need to return the row number for the text "John" and since "John" is repeating several times, I need the last row containing "John".

1. Harry
2. Sara
3. John
4. Harry
5. Harry
6. John

So for the above data which is in a single column, I want to return value 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:A="John"))
```